# Animated heatmap in R

Tags: r, animation, ggplot2, plotly, heatmap

I am trying to make an animated heatmap plot using `ggplot` and (possibly) `plot_ly`. So far I was able to accomplish two partial goals:

1) I can make animated scatterplot using `plot_ly`:

```
dd <- data.frame(f = rep(1:5, c(rep(50, 5))), 
             x = round(runif(250, 10,100),0),
             y = round(runif(250, 10,100),0),
             id = rep(1:50,5)) 

p <- dd %>%
  plot_ly(
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    frame = ~f,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers',
    showlegend = F
  )
p
```

[image: Animated scatter plot]

However, with the `scatter` the plot does not convey the information about repeated elements within a frame or between frames. (So far I wasn't able to get the `plot_ly` with the option `heatmap` to work.)

2) I can generate heatmaps for each step using `ggplot` and `stat_bin2d`.

```
dd.wide <- reshape(dd, direction="wide", timevar = "f")

for (i in seq(2,length(names(dd.wide)),2)){
  p <- ggplot(dd.wide, aes_(x=as.name(names(dd.wide)[i]),y=as.name(names(dd.wide)[i+1]))) +
    stat_bin2d() +
    xlim(10,100) +
    ylim(10,100) +
    guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1, barheight = 5)) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)))
  print(p)
}
```

[image: Step 2] [image: Step 5]

Bot for the second approach I didn't find a simple way of turning these static plots into nice animation (I can make snapshot-movie but I would like to have smoother transitions between images.)

I also tried to use the `ggplotly()` but I wasn't able to get it to work.

I would appreciate any advice on how to make the heatmap change like the scatter plot in `plot_ly` (I am ok using different animation packages).

**Update** I wasn't able to get the animated scatter plot to work on the website so I replaced the animation with a snapshot of the plot.

Comment: Your dropbox link is broken

Comment: Thank you, @camille. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get the animated scatter plot to work on the website so I replaced the animation with a snapshot of the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you looking for something like this:

```
p <- ggplot(data= dd, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  stat_bin2d(aes(frame = f)) +
  xlim(10,100) +
  ylim(10,100) +
  guides(fill = guide_colorbar(barwidth = 1, barheight = 5)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(heat.colors(10)))
p <- ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to do it like that but I got warning `Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: frame` and the output was static.

Comment: see edit. When I click on the play button there is animation.

Comment: I don't have the "play" button only the warning with a static image. Is there a particular version of `ggplot` that you are using?

Comment: I am using `plotly_4.7.1.9000  ggplot2_2.2.1.9000`.

Comment: I have `R 3.5.0`,  `plotly_4.7.1` and `ggplot2_2.2.1`, and I use RStudio. Can that be a problem?

Comment: Yes it could. Especially with the development version of `plotly`.

Comment: I tried to run it from R console but I got this warning: `Warning message:
package ‘devtools::install_github('hadley/ggplot2')’ is not available (for R version 3.5.0) `. Should I downgrade my R?

Comment: You don't have. I also have 3.5. Have you installed the dev version of plotly? Usually, it gives a warning. But if you close and reopen r-studio the dev version will be installed (and ggplot2 too I think).

Comment: I just did and I think it almost works now. For some reason on some of the frame steps the colors don't show up (i.e., everything is gray) but I'll play around with it some more and, hopefully, it will start working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: It works now! Thank you again! I guess it was an issue with the `plotly` version :)